# Issues with Globalize and CarrierWave uploads in Rails 4.2 app

Tags: carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4.2, globalize

I have issues with translated files in my Rails 4.2 app.

### Background

Here are the gem versions I'm using:

```
gem "rails", "4.2.1"
gem "carrierwave" # 0.10.0
gem "globalize" # 5.0.1
```

And my model:

```
class Download < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :download_type
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products

  translates :title, :part_number, :file

  mount_uploader :file, DownloadFileUploader

  validates :title, presence: true

  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{title.parameterize}"
  end
end
```

### The Issues

1. In my view, I want to list a Download and all of the current translations for that download, but all I get is the current locale data for each translation. In the Rails console:

   ```
   > I18n.locale
   => :en

   > download = Download.find(481)
   => #<Download id: 481, title: "SmartSensor HD Quick-reference Guide (User)", part_number: "WX-500-0171", download_type_id: 3, created_at: "2015-01-16 22:49:13", updated_at: "2015-04-20 16:59:25", file: "smartsensor_hd_user_quick-reference_guide-20150116...", download_updated_at: nil>

   > download.translations.count
   => 8

   > download.translated_locales
   => [:de, :en, :es, :fr, :it, :pt, :ru, :"zh-CN"]

   > download.file.class
   => DownloadFileUploader

   > download.file.url
   => "/uploads/download/file/481/smartsensor_hd_user_quick-reference_guide-20150116154913-en.pdf"

   > download.title
   => "SmartSensor HD Quick-reference Guide (User)"

   > download.part_number
   => "WX-500-0171"
   ```

   And when the locale changes:

   ```
   > I18n.locale = :de
   => :de

   > download.file.class
   => DownloadFileUploader

   > download.file.url
   => "/uploads/download/file/481/smartsensor_hd_user_quick-reference_guide-20150116154913-en.pdf"

   > download.title
   => "SmartSensor HD Kurzanleitung"

   > download.part_number
   => "WX-502-0006"
   ```

   If I try and access the translation directly:

   ```
   > I18n.locale = :de
   => :de

   > download.translation.file.class
   => String
   ```
2. If I change how the uploader is mounted in my model:

   ```
   Translation.mount_uploader :file, DownloadFileUploader
   ```

   Existing translations list correctly—including the file, but I can no longer *upload* files. What gets stored in the database is this:

   ```
    /uploads/download/translation/file/401/%23%3CActionDispatch%3A%3AHttp%3A%3AUploadedFile%3A0x007f9c12e6fe00%3E
   ```

   Notice that it inserts `/translation` into the path, which I can fix in the uploader, but the filename isn't actually a file.
3. If I move `translates :title, :part_number, :file` *below* `mount_uploader :file, DownloadFileUploader` in my model, Globalize overrides the mounted uploader and that column is returned as class `String` when accessing it.

### The Cry for Help

Help!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this simple gem https://github.com/dalpo/carrierwave_globalize. which it should allow to use **Globalize** and **Carrierwave** together.

You have to extend your model with the **CarrierwaveGlobalize** module and use the `mount_translated_uploader` class method to mount your carrierwave uploader instead of the `mount_uploader` mehtod.

Follow the instructions in the readme for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but... do not use Globalize with CarrierWave on the same attribute, they both make overrides for the default behavior.

You can do this in your model:

```
class Download < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :download_type
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products

  translates :title, :part_number

  mount_uploader :file, DownloadFileUploader

  validates :title, presence: true

  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{title.parameterize}"
  end
end
```

And then override file storing for your uploader in system to use I18n.locale:

```
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{I18n.locale}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```